# Facing the issue in "OPTION (FAST N)" is sub-query, because of (Migrating the sql server from 2008 to 2016)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

`FASTFIRSTROW` is deprecated after sql server 2008. instead of `FASTFIRSTROW` we are using the replacement of `OPTION (FAST 1)`.

```
select top 1 * from ord o where Ord_ID = 855 option (fast 1)
```

If we use like this we can able to return the query without any issue.

I am trying to use it as sub query but it fails

```
select (select top 1 Client_ID from ord o where ord.Ord_ID = o.Ord_ID option (fast 1) ) As Client,*  from ordRequest ord where ord.Ord_ID = 855
```

Can anyone give the solution for how to use the `OPTION (FAST 1)` inside the subquery?

Comment: `OPTION` goes at the end of a statement, not the middle.

Comment: [Query with a subselect and a query hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/option-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#f-query-with-a-subselect-and-a-query-hint)